# Load information in the initial app load- Redux Toolkit - NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm building an app with NextJS and Redux Toolkit.

I want to load data from cookies and save it in the global state.
And I want to save the data on the first load of the app, no matter which page the user enters.

I created this function that gets the cart from cookies and saves it in the store

```
  const loadCartFromCookies = () => {
    const cookies = Cookie.get('cart');
    if (cookies) {
      const cart = JSON.parse(cookies);
      dispatch(loadCartFromCookiesOrStorage(cart));
    }
  };
```

Then I called it in the _app.tsx

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { loadCartFromCookies } = useCart();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCartFromCookies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SWRConfig
      value={{
        fetcher: (resource, init) =>
          fetch(resource, init).then((res) => res.json()),
      }}
    >
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </SWRConfig>
  );
}
```

But this returns an error

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

So my question is, how can I save information in the store in the initial app loading

Comment: You need to move the `useCart` and `loadCartFromCookies` calls to a component that's wrapped by `<Provider store={store}>` so that the redux store is available to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use "useDispatch" or "useSelector" in _app file, that's why you get this error.
just use "store.dispatch" in React.useEffect hook.